# Stack subscription when routing angular

Tags: arrays, angular, service, routes, subscribe

I have a method that calls an Observable service. I subscribe it and destroy it when navigate, but when I navigate back my method stack the results

> Note: Angular CLI: Version 13.0.2 | npm 8.1.0

```js
  //home component
  
  public workList:workModel[] = [];
  serviceSubscription:Subscription;

  constructor(
    public workService: WorkServices
  ) {

    this.serviceSubscription = this.getWorkList();

   }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.serviceSubscription = this.getWorkList();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.serviceSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  getWorkList(){

    this.workList = [];

    return this.workService.getWorks().subscribe((resp:Array<workModel>) => {
      this.workList = resp.reverse();
      console.log("work list ->", this.workList);
    })
  }
  
  //**************************************************************
  //service
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WorkServices {

    private URL = "http://localhost:3000/work";
    private works:workModel[];

    constructor(
        public http:HttpClient
        ){
            this.works = new Array<workModel>();
    }

    getWorks(){

        return this.http.get(this.URL).pipe(map((resp:any) => {
            resp.forEach((w:workModel) => {
                this.works.push(new workModel(
                    w.description,
                    w.client,
                    w.employees,
                    w.materials,
                    w.isFinished,
                    w.cost,
                    w.id
                )) 
            })
            return this.works;
        }));
    }

/*
Console

work list -> Array [ {…}, {…} ] // load page
work list -> Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ] // Navigate and back first time
work list -> Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ] // Navigate and back second time
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the results are cached in your service, in the `works` array. If this behavior is not desired, then you can simply remove the `works` property from the service and remove the usage of it from the `getWorks` method:

```
getWorks() {
  return this.http.get(this.URL).pipe(
    map((resp: any) => resp.map((w: workModel) =>
      new workModel(
        w.description,
        w.client,
        w.employees,
        w.materials,
        w.isFinished,
        w.cost,
        w.id
      ))
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't see you destroying the observable, the works array is in service, and service is not destroyed. so it keeps the data. there are three ways to solve this

1. Clear works array when component is destroyed.
2. include service in provider array of component so service instance destroys with component.

   ```
   @Component({providers:[WorkServices]})
   ```
3. Reinitialize works array everytime getWorks is called.

The solution depends totally on your usecase. ideally works array shouldn't be managed in service until you have a particular scenario.